# SQL getting values from one table excluding others with minus

Tags: mysql, sql

I must create a query that finds all employee names and salary where the salary is between 2000 and 15000 but not in the range of 5000 and 10000

I am trying to do it with the minus operator and it looks just like examples in all tutorials but it doesnt work

```
select first_name, last_name, salary from hr.employees where salary between 2000 and 15000
minus
select first_name, last_name, salary from hr.employees where salary not between 5000 and 10000
```

MySQL workbench also says minus is not valid at this position

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to put the conditions all in one query?  `select ... where ( salary >= 2000 and salary < 5000 ) or ( salary > 5000 and salary <= 15000 )` ?

Comment: @DanFarrell I must use minus operator for the exercise .. I went through few tutorials and it always looks like that except for semicolon at last query but it gives the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MySQL` does not support the `minus` operator at all. You have to emulate its behaviour.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, salary 
  FROM hr.employees 
 WHERE salary BETWEEN 2000 AND 15000
   AND salary NOT BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000
```